# Exceeding message size than MaximumReceiveMessageSize property of SignalR causes disconnection of active session

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub, signalr.client, asp.net-core-signalr

[MaximumReceiveMessageSize](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr.huboptions.maximumreceivemessagesize?view=aspnetcore-3.1) Property of SignalR HubOptions restricts the maximum size of incoming hub message.
However, if the message size is higher than the max-size defined using the property, the connection is terminated.

Is there any options/flag available in [aspnetCore.signalR](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.signalr?view=aspnetcore-3.1) which rejects the incoming message with an exception but allows future traffic over the same channel i.e. the channel is not disconnected if for any message the maximum message size is violated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no available options for that.

Comment: Is there any documentation behind this design on why the entire connection is terminated, rather than rejecting the specific message?

Comment: The client is considered malicious if it sends more than the max size.